# Can openmp be used to parallelise code over multiple CPUs on one board?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Can openmp be used to parallelise over multiple physical processors on one board or will I need to combine openmp with mpi to achive this?

Comment: Yes, it can, as long as both CPUs share their memory space and the OS can dispatch threads to both of them at the same time. This is usually the case with most modern OSes and multisocket hardware architectures.